# Relation between Kendall tau distance and the number random swaps

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, permutations

Let $r = [1, 2, ..., n]$ be a list of size $n$. Each element is unique and the purpose of the number is to identify the element (the value in itself is not of interest).

We define a procedure to generate new permutations of this list:

- A position $i$ is drawn at random from {1, ..., n-1} and the elements at positions $i$ and $i+1$ are inverted.
- We repeat this operation $s$ times.

Suppose we generate two lists, A and B, using this procedure independently on the same initial list $r$. We then compute the Kendall distance $\tau(A, B)$ defined as the minimal number of "neighbor swaps" needed to transform A into B.

**What is the relation between $s$ and $\tau(A, B)$ ?**

Not surprisingly, $s$ is increasing faster in comparison to $\tau$, as shown in the following plot. But what is the formula?

[image: empirical plot]

Figure: $\frac{s}{n}$ compared to empirical estimation of $\tau(A, B)$ with $n=20$ and $100$ trials averaged to compute each point.